# Conditional Regex for Percentage based values

Tags: regex, networking

I've never been very good at regex, but I really need to grab the percentage information from these log entries; however, the warn/critical message moves around depending on where the warning was located in either the In or the Out utilization. I just can't figure out the regex. Here are two example entries that show both in and out issues:

```
    ["XXXXXXX"], (up), MAC: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, Speed: 2 GBit/s, In: 0 Bit/s (0%), Out: 6.53 GBit/s (warn/crit at 1.6 GBit/s/1.8 GBit/s) (326.45%)(!!)   
    ["XXXXXXX"], (up), MAC: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, Speed: 2 GBit/s, In: 0 Bit/s (warn/crit at 1.6 GBit/s/1.8 GBit/s) (95.45%), Out: 6.53 GBit/s (32.00%)(!!)
```

Ultimately I need to use capture groups to capture both the in and out utilization percentage. But every regex I try only finds a single percentage. Help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT SHOWING EXPECTED RESULT:

for each line the regex capture groups would identify in and out so the program can see both the in and out utilization. The program is expecting a key value pair from every log entry like the following:

IN:0% OUT:326.45%

IN:95.45% OUT:32.00%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
In:.+\(([0-9\.]+%)\).+Out:.+\(([0-9\.]+%)
```

If you just need to pull out values with percentage information, then it can help

https://regex101.com/r/B9pZeO/1

Comment: I wish it was that easy. That's what I had tried first. But the capture groups are what is killing me. Updating original question to show expected result.

Comment: @JustinBoucher got it, i updated the example. You won't be able to get that exact output in a regular expression. But in the updated example, "In" will belong to the first group, "Out" to the second.

Comment: Thank you so much. You don't know how much i hate regex. lol